# Tensorflow import error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am installing tensorflow (Window 11), for first time by following this sites help:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native
- https://youtu.be/KZFn0dvPZUQ
- https://deeplizard.com/learn/video/IubEtS2JAiY

I am already installed [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe), `CUDA 11.8.0`, `cuDNN SDK 8.6.0`

Execute the following command using `Anaconda Prompt Terminal`

1. `conda create --name tf python=3.9`
2. `pip install --upgrade pip`
3. `pip install "tensorflow<2.11"`

Then, when I do this:
`import tensorflow as tf`
The following error are show:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'
```

I have already check whether tensorflow is installed properly:

```
(tf) C:\Users\ASUS>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.10.1
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: d:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, keras, keras-preprocessing, libclang, numpy, opt-einsum, packaging, protobuf, setuptools, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, typing-extensions, wrapt
Required-by:
```

Try **uninstalling** and **reinstalling tensorflow** but the error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import tensorflow as tf`

seems to load tensorflow from `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39` so you are not running the correct python interpreter from your conda env `d:\anaconda\envs\tf`. `pip show tensorflow` shows you the version installed in  `d:\anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages` so you are looking at different python installations.

So however you are running your code, make sure that you use the correct python interpreter. Consider uninstalling the python version at `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39` completly